# Apache not rendering Bugzilla cgi

Tags: 14.04, apache2, cgi, bugzilla

I've just tried to install Bugzilla on my machine for test purposes. I'm going to evaluate the Bugzilla REST API for a company i'm currently interning at. The problem is that when I go to `http://localhost/bugzilla/` this is what i'm seeing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#
# This Source Code Form is "Incompatible With Secondary Licenses", as
# defined by the Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0.

###############################################################################
# Script Initialization
###############################################################################

# Make it harder for us to do dangerous things in Perl.
use strict;

# Include the Bugzilla CGI and general utility library.
use lib qw(. lib);

use Bugzilla;
use Bugzilla::Constants;
use Bugzilla::Error;
use Bugzilla::Update;

# Check whether or not the user is logged in
my $user = Bugzilla->login(LOGIN_OPTIONAL);
my $cgi = Bugzilla->cgi;
my $template = Bugzilla->template;
my $vars = {};

# And log out the user if requested. We do this first so that nothing
# else accidentally relies on the current login.
if ($cgi->param('logout')) {
    Bugzilla->logout();
    $user = Bugzilla->user;
    $vars->{'message'} = "logged_out";
    # Make sure that templates or other code doesn't get confused about this.
    $cgi->delete('logout');
}

###############################################################################
# Main Body Execution
###############################################################################

# Return the appropriate HTTP response headers.
print $cgi->header();

if ($user->in_group('admin')) {
    # If 'urlbase' is not set, display the Welcome page.
    unless (Bugzilla->params->{'urlbase'}) {
        $template->process('welcome-admin.html.tmpl')
          || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
        exit;
    }
    # Inform the administrator about new releases, if any.
    $vars->{'release'} = Bugzilla::Update::get_notifications();
}

# Generate and return the UI (HTML page) from the appropriate template.
$template->process("index.html.tmpl", $vars)
  || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
```

I added

```
<directory /var/www/>
Addhandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</directory>
```

to the 000-default.conf file to allow CGI-script in all areas.

Comment: Where is a2enmod located? I do not seem to find it in my Apache setup.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/a2enmod` - See the Following http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-disable-apache-modules-under-linux-unix/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My CGI module was not enabled.

I went to the terminal and typed `a2enmod` which then gave me a choice of modules to enable. I entered `cgi`, it enabled it. Then I ran `service apache2 restart` and that solved my problem.