# Cannot get bugzilla to work on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: server, webserver, bugzilla

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS installed on my server computer. I've installed LAMP during installation process and phpmyadmin after that, which works without any problems. Then I've downloaded bugzilla-4.4.6 and extracted it into `/usr/local/bugzilla-4.4.6`. In `/var/www/html/bugzilla` I've created softlink to extracted directory:

```
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html$ ls -asl
total 20
 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 28 08:50 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Dec 28 08:49 ..
 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    25 Dec 28 08:50 bugzilla -> /usr/local/bugzilla-4.4.6
12 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Dec 27 22:40 index.html
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html$
```

Following code chunk was then added to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
        AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then, I've restarted apache web server:

```
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
 AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. 
 Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[ OK ]
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html$
```

Apache test page works without problems, but if I try to get bugzilla page with `http://192.168.0.101/bugzilla`, I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /bugzilla was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.7
(Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.101 Port 80
```

I've also succesfully created mysql user AND database and accordingly updated `localconfig` and then ran `sudo sudo ./checksetup.pl`. Here is ouput:

```
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html/bugzilla$ sudo ./checksetup.pl
[sudo] password for xxx: 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "sl_SI.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
* This is Bugzilla 4.4.6 on perl 5.18.2
* Running on Linux 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v4.04 
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.84_01 
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.23)     ok: found v2.24 
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     ok: found v1.12 
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.71)     ok: found v1.83 
Checking for                  DBI (v1.614)    ok: found v1.63 
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     ok: found v2.26 
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.04)     ok: found v2.199 
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.928 
Checking for                  URI (v1.37)     ok: found v1.65 
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.32)     ok: found v0.402 
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004 

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found 
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.025 
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v2.7.0)    not found 
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     ok: found v1.46 

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.56 
Checking for                Chart (v2.1.0)    not found 
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       not found 
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       not found 
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       not found 
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    ok: found v5.505 
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v6.06 
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       not found 
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    ok: found v0.9.6 
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       ok: found v0.64 
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.16 
Checking for         Net-SMTP-SSL (v1.01)     ok: found v1.01 
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       ok: found v0.24 
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v1.12 
Checking for          XMLRPC-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v0.717 
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       ok: found v1.06 
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      ok: found v3.01 
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Test/Taint.pm line 329, <DATA> line 751.
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       ok: found v1.06 
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.67)     ok: found v3.71 
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       ok: found v0.11 
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok: found v2.49 
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       ok: found v1.01 
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       ok: found v1.203 
Checking for HTML-FormatText-WithLinks (v0.13)     ok: found v0.14 
Checking for          TheSchwartz (v1.07)     ok: found v1.11 
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       ok: found v0.84 
Checking for           File-Slurp (v9999.13)  ok: found v9999.19 
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) ok: found v2.000008 
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found 
Checking for        File-MimeInfo (any)       ok: found v0.26 
Checking for           IO-stringy (any)       ok: found v2.110 
Checking for              mod_env (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_expires (any)       not found 
Checking for          mod_headers (any)       not found 
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*      MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                               *
***********************************************************************
*            Chart * New Charts, Old Charts                           *
*      Template-GD * Graphical Reports                                *
*       GDTextUtil * Graphical Reports                                *
*          GDGraph * Graphical Reports                                *
*         XML-Twig * Move Bugs Between Installations, Automatic Update Notifications *
* Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                                         *
***********************************************************************
* APACHE MODULES                                                      *
***********************************************************************
* Normally, when Bugzilla is upgraded, all Bugzilla users have to     *
* clear their browser cache or Bugzilla will break. If you enable     *
* certain modules in your Apache configuration (usually called        *
* httpd.conf or apache2.conf) then your users will not have to clear  *
* their caches when you upgrade Bugzilla. The modules you need to     *
* enable are:                                                         *
*                                                                     *
*    mod_expires, mod_headers                                         *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

          Chart: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Chart::Lines
    Template-GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template::Plugin::GD::Image
     GDTextUtil: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Text
        GDGraph: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Graph
       XML-Twig: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl XML::Twig
Apache-SizeLimit: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Apache2::SizeLimit


To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all

Reading ./localconfig...

OPTIONAL NOTE: If you want to be able to use the 'difference between two
patches' feature of Bugzilla (which requires the PatchReader Perl module
as well), you should install patchutils from:

    http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/

Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.025
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
Fixing file permissions...

Now that you have installed Bugzilla, you should visit the 'Parameters'
page (linked in the footer of the Administrator account) to ensure it
is set up as you wish - this includes setting the 'urlbase' option to
the correct URL.
checksetup.pl complete.
xxx@conquistador:/var/www/html/bugzilla$
```

What did I miss?? 192.168.0.101 is static IP of server with Ubuntu Server Software (on LAN). Now, are maybe permissions problem, since I must run `checksetup` with sudo? Or is it maybe the fact that I've installed all perl modules and whenever I run `checksetup` I still got some modules uninstalled and there are two versions of perl on my server?! And why I cannot find httpd.conf under apache installation for virtualhosts setup? Here is also `error.log` file from apache:

```
xxx@conquistador:~$ tail -n10 /var/log/apache2/error.log 
[Mon Dec 29 06:51:30.917242 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7816] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 29 06:51:31.981406 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7869] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 29 06:51:31.981522 2014] [core:notice] [pid 7869] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Dec 29 10:20:37.140342 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7869] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 29 10:21:17.627440 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1200] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 29 10:21:17.673547 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1200] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Dec 29 11:09:48.663528 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1200] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 29 11:09:49.716595 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2395] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 29 11:09:49.716748 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2395] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Dec 29 11:15:22.206391 2014] [core:error] [pid 2401] [client 87.236.31.27:51667] AH00135: Invalid method in request +\xd9J\xac\xc6\x86\x8a\x9fgJI\x10
xxx@conquistador:~$
```

I have restarted server via `sudo reboot now` and now if I go to `http://192.168.0.101/bugzilla/` I do not get `not found error` any more, but following output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#
# This Source Code Form is "Incompatible With Secondary Licenses", as
# defined by the Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0.

###############################################################################
# Script Initialization
###############################################################################

# Make it harder for us to do dangerous things in Perl.
use strict;

# Include the Bugzilla CGI and general utility library.
use lib qw(. lib);

use Bugzilla;
use Bugzilla::Constants;
use Bugzilla::Error;
use Bugzilla::Update;

# Check whether or not the user is logged in
my $user = Bugzilla->login(LOGIN_OPTIONAL);
my $cgi = Bugzilla->cgi;
my $template = Bugzilla->template;
my $vars = {};

# And log out the user if requested. We do this first so that nothing
# else accidentally relies on the current login.
if ($cgi->param('logout')) {
    Bugzilla->logout();
    $user = Bugzilla->user;
    $vars->{'message'} = "logged_out";
    # Make sure that templates or other code doesn't get confused about this.
    $cgi->delete('logout');
}

###############################################################################
# Main Body Execution
###############################################################################

# Return the appropriate HTTP response headers.
print $cgi->header();

if ($user->in_group('admin')) {
    # If 'urlbase' is not set, display the Welcome page.
    unless (Bugzilla->params->{'urlbase'}) {
        $template->process('welcome-admin.html.tmpl')
          || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
        exit;
    }
    # Inform the administrator about new releases, if any.
    $vars->{'release'} = Bugzilla::Update::get_notifications();
}

# Generate and return the UI (HTML page) from the appropriate template.
$template->process("index.html.tmpl", $vars)
  || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
```

Now, what the hell is going on now?!

Comment: @MarkoFrelih probably unrelated, but why `Alias /bugzilla /var/www/html/bugzilla`? The default `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html`, so `/bugzilla` will go to `/var/www/html/bugzilla` by default anyway.

Comment: VirtualHost setup is done via the `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` folders, and the `a2ensite`, `a2dissite` commands.

Comment: - The warnings for perl are benign. The checker seems to believe everything is installed correctly.... Next one: check the apache logs in /var/log/ :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache not rendering Bugzilla cgi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488811/apache-not-rendering-bugzilla-cgi), also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172518/cannot-run-cgi-show-plain-text-only-ubuntu-13-10-apache-2-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it!!! I've enabled cgi in apache via `sudo a2enmod cgi` and now works!